# How do I set the #default_value of a select list to the first option?

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently using hook_form_alter and $form['#after_build'] to try and set a term reference select list's default value to the first option in the list. I'm using the [Reference Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module in my content type, and even though the first item appears to be selected (because the field is set to Required), it's not. With help from the Devel module, I checked, and the #default_value is definitely empty. The closest I've gotten is with this:

```
function set_keywords_after_build($form, &$form_state) { 
    $keyword = $form['field_product_keyword']['und']['#options']; 
    $form['field_product_keyword']['und']['#default_value'] = $keyword; 
return $form; 
}
```

Looking at the page array, this will set the default value to:

```
#default_value (Array, 1 element) 
 - 13 (String, 19 characters ) KeywordName
```

where 13 is the tid of KeywordName.

Looking at another term reference field in the same form, it should look something like this:

```
#default_value (Array, 1 element)
 - 0 (String, 2 characters ) 38
```

Where 38 is the tid and 0 (I'm assuming) is the key?

Comment: Update: I scrapped the "#after_build" part and am now just using hook_form_alter, but I don't know what to add to the submit handler function. I should note that these nodes are being created by a Feeds import, and no manual editing or saving will be performed on them.

`function set_keywords_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'part_node_form') {
 $keyword = $form['field_product_keyword']['und']['#options']; 
 $form['field_product_keyword']['und']['#default_value'][0] = $keyword;
 $form["#submit"][] = 'set_keywords_form_submit';
  }
}`

Comment: Your $keyword is a whole array, where you only want the '13' that is the index of the entry.  `$form['field_product_keyword']['und']['#default_value'][] = key($keyword);`  See [get first key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028668/get-first-key-in-a-possibly-associative-array) question.  The empty bracket `[]` will be set to 0 and mimic that other term reference field.  You could also use `[0]`